# MSMQ Permissions

Tags: msmq

Where can I find a list of the MSMQ permissions and what they really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the TechNet article "[Securing Your MSMQ Enterprise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723255.aspx)", as it lists all of the permissions, as well as descriptions (short ones, at least) for MSMQ from the enterprise level to the queue level.